# Compile using a function from a library

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, arm

I am trying to compile using a custom library with the purpose of use one function. In my example, this function is **test** and it is inside the library **mylibrary.so**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* message = "test";
    test(message);
    exit(0);
}
```

I have tried to compile using:

```
 $ gcc -Wimplicit-function-declaration hack.c -o hack
hack.c: In function 'main':
hack.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'test' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  test(message);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/ccImBtlh.o: In function `main':
hack.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In addition, if I add the custom library to the linker. I have more errors.

```
$ gcc -L/home/user/my/path/ -lmylibrary hack.c -o hack
hack.c: In function 'main':
hack.c:11:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'test' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  test(message);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblog.so, needed by /home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by /home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libstdc++.so, needed by /home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so: undefined reference to `getpid@LIBC'
/home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so: undefined reference to `iscntrl@LIBC'
/home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so: undefined reference to `tolower@LIBC'
/home/user/my/path/libmylibrary.so: undefined reference to `sleep@LIBC'
...
```

Also, I have tried to use another libc, but I still with the same problem.

I would like to know how to use a function of a custom library (mylibrary.so).

**EDIT**
*To add more info:* It is a library used by an android apk and I am trying to use in another ARM device. So, I think that my problem is with the libc that mylibrary.so is using.

Comment: what is `/my/path/`? Please use the actual path of the filesystem where `libmylibrary.a` file is located. For e.g. if `libmylibrary.a` is inside `/usr/lib` then use `-L/usr/lib`.

Comment: The /my/path is /home/user/my/path. It was just an example. But my problem is twith the references of mylibrary.so. "undefined reference to `getpid@LIBC'"

Comment: As it needs libstdc++, i think your library is using c++...

Comment: I have added this library too, but it still doesn't compile. So, is it possible to add a function from mylibrary.so? (Also, I tried to compile with g++)

Comment: @sinkmanu Use `-lmylibrary` after the name of the c file you are compiling. `gcc -L/home/user/my/path/ hack.c -o hack -lmylibrary`

Comment: You should add the prototype of the function `test(const char*)`. Usually this is provided with the used library. Check if you have an appropriate header file and use `#include'.

Comment: @harper I don't have any header file, just the compiled library

Comment: If you don't have header files then you have guessed the prototype. That's encouraged. I think. But you should write it down, so the compiler can check that you passed correct arguments. This gives you also a documentation of the Interface you are using. This can help when you come back to the Project after a period of time.